# Trying to cause a "worse case" quicksort

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, quicksort

I implemented a quicksort implementation in C and I'm trying to figure out what input is needed to cause a worse case performance.

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort):

> always choosing the last element in the partition as the pivot in this way results in poor performance (n^2) on already sorted lists, or lists of identical elements.

So I tried to do that, which resulted in [the following code](https://gist.github.com/r-darwish/4793ca7da98aadab5209). The pivot is always the last element and the input is an already sorted list.

In order to prove that the complexity is indeed n^2, I created a global variable which I increment in each iteration, then finally print it.

I'd expected that the program would print:

```
Done in 64 iterations
```

However, it did it in 28 iterations. Maybe my understanding of the term "complexity" is wrong?

Comment: `n*(n-1)/2 = 8*7/2 = 28`. `n*(n-1)/2` is still O(n^2).

Comment: @darwish handsome avatar ;)

Comment: Take a bigger input (like 10^5 elements), you will immediately know it is O(n^2).

Comment: @VinayakGarg: Immediately? It's going to take quadratically longer become 'obvious'.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: No it is "immediately" only :) Because when the result won't come "immediately" (as expected from Quick sort), you will know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In every iteration, the list shrinks by one element because the pivot is moved and no longer counted. So, the total amount of iterations is 7+6+5+4+3+2+1 = 28.

Note that this is still quadratic, because it is equal to `n*(n-1)/2`.

Answer (score 1):

The number of iterations is 28 for n=8.

The number of iterations is equal to `n*(n-1)/2` = 8*7/2 = 28.

Now the function is **f(n)=n*(n-1)/2 = n<sup>2</sup>/2 - n/2**.

There for **f(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>/2 - n/2) = O((1/2)n<sup>2</sup>) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

Thus for your input is in fact the worst case for Quicksort.